# how to store an image captured on camera directly into a cloud server using qt?

Tags: qt, c++11, google-cloud-storage

I have to take a picture from the camera of the device and send the image directly into a cloud server, I am very new to Cloud and storage so I need some help with this topic.

I am successfully able to open up the camera and take a picture and store the picture into my local storage. please help me to expand this code.

```
Main_management::Main_management(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    cam=new QCamera();
    cam->setCaptureMode(QCamera::CaptureStillImage);
    view=new QCameraViewfinder();
    view->show();
    cam->setViewfinder(view);
    vb1.addWidget(view,10,Qt::AlignTop);
    pb=new QPushButton("capture");
    vb1.addWidget(pb,0,Qt::AlignBottom);
    this->setLayout(&vb1);
    imageCapture=new QCameraImageCapture(cam);
    cam->start();
    connect(pb,SIGNAL(clicked()),SLOT(Capture_image()));
        cam->start();
}

Main_management::~Main_management()
{

}

void Main_management::Capture_image()
{
    qDebug()<<Q_FUNC_INFO<<endl;
        imageCapture->capture("C:/Users/vinay/Documents");
    }
```

as you can see in the slot i am storing the image onto the local storage please can somone guide me as how to use any cloud storage API's and push the image onto a server.

Comment: You should do it by sending that file to whatever cloud storage you want using their API. For sure, you will have to do it using Qt Network classes line QNetworkAccessManager

Comment: can you please give an example code of how to do that or any link that i can refer which has some examples in it?

Comment: here is an example of authentication:
https://www.qt.io/blog/2017/01/25/connecting-qt-application-google-services-using-oauth-2-0
you will have to implement JSON API for your app using guideline in https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos

Comment: After implementing the JSON API for your app to ensure the correct authentication. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-cpp) is a relevant code sample on how to upload any object to Google Cloud Storage using C++.

Comment: can i have an example code as to how to implement google's json api in my QT app or any app for that matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that [a bucket is already created](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets) in Cloud Storage.

To upload the image from your local storage to Cloud Storage use the Cloud Client Libraries for the Google Cloud Storage API. In order to achieve this with C++ you'll basically need to follow three steps:

1. [Installing the client library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-cpp/blob/master/README.md).
2. Create a service account, download the service account key and set up an environment variable for authentication.
3. Create a client and use the `client.UploadFile()` method to upload the file from your local storage to Cloud Storage.

For steps 1. and 2. please refer to [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#setting_up_authentication) documentation. Find a comprehensive example code for step 3. on the following [section](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-cpp) of the documentation.

Comment: thank you for helping me out! got it working only today :)